# iOS Youtube iframe bug

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, youtube

I am playing an embedded Youtube video (iframe) on iOS. I want to manipulate the iframe's size dynamically with javascript. I noticed that when I change the frame's size with javascript, the video is not playing (not clickable) on iOS (on pc/android it is ok).

I simulated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/efraimya/AAFL9/6/). If I remove the javascript the video is playing again!

I think that it is related to a change on Youtube's code, because it is an old code that used to work until somewhere last week.

Any ideas?

thanks!

The code:

```
<iframe id="aa" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/54vtXRI32MQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

js:

```
$('iframe').css({'height' : '250px'});
$('iframe').css({'width' : '400px'});
```

Comment: Why are you setting wisth and height in two calls and not one. `$('iframe').css({'height' : '250px', 'width' : '400px'});`

Comment: This is only a test. Why is it related? I have changed it to one line, still same bug: http://jsfiddle.net/efraimya/AAFL9/11/

Comment: Apparently this is Google's bug (#10, #11). #14's workaround solved my problem!  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=video+tag&colspec=API+ID+Type+Status+Priority+Stars+Summary&groupby&sort&id=4569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is Google's [bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=video%20tag&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby&sort&id=4569) (#10, #11). #14's workaround solved my problem!